# Fast json Deserialization with Map as field

Tags: json, scala, performance, serialization, apache-flink

I want to deserialize an Array[Byte] that is in Json format to the Event class described below and I want to do it as fast as possible. The Event class has a couple Int/String fields which shouldn't be a problem. All the contents of the json formatted Byte array must be transformed to a Map. The keys of the of the json/Map are unknown and there aren't any nested jsonObjects or arrays.

E.g Json: {"someKey1": "someval", "someInt": 34, "anotherKey": 56} -> toMap

Here's what I've done so far

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsObject, Json}

...

  override def line2Event(
                           line: Array[Byte],
                           id: Int
                         ): Event = {
    val map = Json.parse(line).as[JsObject].value.toMap
    val timestamp = map.getOrElse("timestamp", id).toString.toLong
    Event(id, "GenericJson", timestamp, map)


class Event(
             val id: Int,
             val eventType: String,
             val timestamp: Long,
             extraArgs: Map[String, Any]
           )
```

The speed for this play api implementation for some dataset is about 25K messages/second. I would like to improve it. Would the use of some other framework help? Something like [jsoniter](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala) for example?

In my case, however, I don't have a class with specific fields (i.e, all the key-value pairs of the json are stored to the Map field of the Event). Does this or another framework include a parse method like the one that I use but faster?

Comment: There are some repositories in github the compare performance between jaon libraries in Scala. One for example is: https://github.com/yanns/scala-json-parsers-performance

Comment: Your best bet is to just try things. Play json is a relatively slow json implementation on scala. jsoniter will almost certainly be faster. Circe is my personal preference mostly because of the API, but it's also usually faster than play json.

Comment: Could you please explain how `Event` values are used? Should they be just serialized as JSON to some response message or somehow differently? Do you have a possibility to change the `Event` class definition?

Comment: @AndriyPlokhotnyuk Unfortunately I can't change the Event class. Can you can provide me with a way to deserialize an Array[Byte] (that has json inside) to an immutable.Map[String, Any] with jsoniter?

Comment: @user3161227 You can use [a custom codec like it was used in the dijon library for that](https://github.com/jvican/dijon/blob/c8d9be125b66ab06e0c73038ef2242a6110e434f/dijon/src/main/scala/dijon/package.scala#L163-L239).

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/evolution-gaming/play-json-tools/blob/c665d94e60fafa4f7abee0b1785091c7d1c30fa0/play-json-jsoniter/src/main/scala/com/evolutiongaming/jsonitertool/JsonValueCodecJsValue.scala#L11-L105) is the same kind of custom codec but for play-json AST.

Comment: Hmm, isnt there a way for the parameter of the codec to be directly immutable.Map?

Comment: BEWARE that [Scala's maps are vulnerable under DoS attacks which exploit hash code collisions](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203). So if your input is not from trusted counterparties then you would need to implement safe `immutable.Map` for yourself.

Comment: regardless of this vulnerability implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[Map[String, Any]] = JsonCodecMaker.make throws an exception about sealed traits due the the value being Any. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've also tried using jackson parsing

```
  lazy val module = new MapModule{}
  lazy val mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
  .addModule(module)
  .build()
  ...
  val map: Map[String, Any] = mapper.readValue(line, classOf[Map[String, Any]])
```

As I needed an immutable scala map note that I have also registered the DefaultScalaModule.

Unfortunately since this class is used inside Flink it needs to be serializable and DefaultScalaModule is not (ObjectMapper is). Similar problem arose with other libs (like jsoniter). What to do? Should I create a new queston?

EDIT: I used lazy vals for the mapper and the scalaModule (got the MapModule only) and they are now initialized when they are needed (i.e., in the flink worker). [See "I have a NotSerializableException." part](https://flink.apache.org/gettinghelp.html)

The speed is about 80K events/second which is at least 3 times faster from the previous implementation. Perhaps parsing the byte array directly to Map would also be as fast with play json but I couldnt find a way to do it.